# Ruby On Rails 6, gender validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to set the gender validation depending on the penultimate digit of the PESEL number (if the digit is even, then the gender is 'female'). For now my Profile.rb look like that:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: %i[male female]
  validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :gender, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :pesel, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :contact_number, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :pesel, format: { with: /\A(\d{11})\z/ }, on: :update
  validate :gender_correct?

def gender_correct?
  return self.pesel.blank?
  if self.pesel[-2].to_i % 2 != 0
   pesel_gender = 'male'
  else
   pesel_gender = 'female'
  end
  if pesel_gender != self.gender
   errors.add(:gender, t('activerecord.errors.models.profile.attributes.gender.wrong'))
  end
end
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Other validations works fine.

EDIT:

My update action:

```
 def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      @profile.avatar.attach(params[:avatar]) if params[:avatar].present?
      if @profile.errors.empty? && @profile.update(profile_params)
        @profile.onboarded = true
        @profile.save
        @profile.fill_info!
        @profile.assign_dispensary
        format.html { redirect_to authenticated_root_path, notice: t('.update.success') }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render 'pages/info', alert: t('.update.error') }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If i tried to update profile with blank first/last name, pesel, gender or contact number,then an error is displayed below text field.

Before update:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uS30WKLBFt5jcUUycI4CQblnEOpkrWEc/view?usp=sharing

After update:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJqk-0opJdoZQ37CkPwscfL8Ohb19n6A/view?usp=sharing

I wanted to display error "PESEL does not match the set gender. Correct the PESEL number." under gender text field if PESEL gender doesn't match selected gender. Is that enough info? Or should I add something else?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not something we can act on. You have posted the code, that's good. But what we also like to see is description of how exactly it doesn't work (what do you expect? what happens instead?) and code to reproduce this on our machines.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Okay, so I edited my question. i hope this is enough info (I forgot to mention, that I am a beginner in Rails)

Comment: I guess you want `return if self.pesel.blank?` instead of `return self.pesel.blank?`

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for that. I wasn't sure if I needed to type "if" there.

Comment: @spickermann Aaand that was that. Missing "if" after return.Now it works as it should. I just had to add "I18n" to the "t('activerecord.error(...)"